# What are some ways to scramble a matrix based on a 256 bit key?

Tags: c++, matrix, encryption, encoding, obfuscation

Looking to build an algorithm that will scramble a matrix based on a 256-bit key.  Given two m*n matrices A and B and key K, I would like A and B to be scrambled in the same way.  So informally, if A==B, scramble(A,K)==scramble(B,K).

What I'm trying to do seems to have similarities to encryption, but I'm wholly unfamiliar with the field.  I feel like there must be some things I can leverage from encryption algorithms to make the process fast and computationally efficient.

To clarify, the main purpose of the scrambling is to obfuscate the matrix content while still allowing for comparisons to be made.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific on what you need it for? currently `int scramble(Matrix A,Key K) { return 1;}` fullfils your requirements ;)

Comment: [S-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-box) and [P-box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_box) is something you could start with.

Comment: Represent the matrix as 1d array and encrypt it with your 256-bit key.

Comment: how do you define "scramble" ? Is that changing the order ? Or making them unreadable ? Does it have to be reversible ? Does it have to resist attempts to un-scramble without the key ?

Comment: Are you looking for encryption like AES 256 or some sort of salted hash, maybe? Either could be applied to the serialized data.

Comment: Doesn't need to be reversible @SanderDeDycker, the main purpose is to make it unreadable.  Specifically the matrixes are images. with the values being pixels.

Comment: I don't think you have clarified anything. What do you mean by "comparisons"? Comparisons for equality, or something else?

Comment: @JamesKPolk I want to be able to still calculate the dot product between the two matrices and have the result be the same as it would be on the unscrambled version.

Comment: Unfortunately the dot product of *two matrices* is not something I'm aware of. Did you mean the *product* of the two matrices?

Comment: @JamesKPolk The dot product of the flattened matrices; sorry.  

So for a 2x2, (a b c d) ⋅ (e f g h) == (a d b c) ⋅ (e h f g)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you might need [Cryptographic hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function). Feeding your matrix/image into one generates (almost) unique hash value for it. This hash value is convenient, as it's constant size and usually much smaller than the source data. It's practically impossible to go from the hash value back to original data, and hashing the same image data again yields the same hash value.

If you want to add a secret key into this, you can concatenate the image data and the key, and compute hash over that. With the same data and key you'll receive the same hash value, and if you change either, the hash value changes.

(almost unique: by pigeonhole principle, turning a large input into smaller hash value, there must be multiple inputs that generate the same hash value. In practice, this is rarely a concern)

Comment: A hash algorithm with a key is more correctly called a [message authentication code, or MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code). If you want cryptographic strength for this MAC then you should use an established MAC, for example [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC), rather than an ad-hoc construction such as you've suggested.

Comment: Excellent point @JamesKPolk - thank you. I was so focused on how much this looks like hashed, salted passwords, that I missed completely the existence of MACs.

Comment: This won't exactly work.  The output needs to remain a matrix, so I can still compute similarity between scramble(A) and scramble(B) by computing the dot product

Comment: I guess you'd also want that A dot B is equal to (or close to) scramble(A) dot scramble(B). For that, you'd need something different, indeed. I think using the key to shuffle the elements in the array would work, but that doesn't hide the matrix contents really well.